# New to EJB:Missing Deploy Tool

Tags: jboss, glassfish, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I am new to EJB.I am reading **EJB HeadFirst** to understand various EJB concepts.Throughout the book the author is using the deploy tool that comes with the J2ee server (as specified in the book).So i also downloaded j2ee server from this url[Sun Java System Application Server Platform Edition Multi-language 8.2 FCS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-glassfish-419424.html#sjsas_pe-8_2-oth-JPR)

I installed it but i cannot find the deploy tool present in server bin directory.So could anyone please help me out on how to deploy an EJB application on a server.

Comment: I would not start learning Java EE 5 when we have Java EE 6 which is much more advanced. Check out these tutorials: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/ and consider using NetBeans and Glassfish in order to understand what's going on in this environment.

Comment: EJB HeadFirst, if I remember right, explains EJB 2 and not EJB 3. EJB 3 is way simplified and it would be a waste of time if you started with EJB 2. I'd rather recommend "EJB in Action" by Reza Rehman and Debu Panda. For a server, I love Apache TomEE (that's tomcat bundled with openejb) so deploying etc, is just like how you would do with tomcat.

Comment: and talking about deploy tool, for learning purposes, you can learn almost any EJB concept by running against EJB 3.1 standalone embeddable container (most vendors provide one). So you'd not need to package and deploy in a server to verify but just run a simple JUnit test, standalone. That really saves a lot of time :) http://ci.apache.org/projects/openejb/examples-generated/index.html has many examples against OpenEJB standalone container.

Comment: As guys advices I wouldn't start with HeadFirst also. In my opinion the best available book is "Enterprise Java Beans 3.0" by Bill Burke (the newest EJB spec is 3.1, but concepts are generally the same - 3.1 has some new features, by those explained in this book are not outdated). What's more the great source of examples if JBoss EJB3 tutorial: http://www.jboss.org/ejb3/docs These are available with source code, which can be easily deployed on JBoss server - just compile and copy to deploy directory (it's described in details in this tutorial). Good luck!